# Convert Excel VBA to Python or any faster software

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a excel vba which works by checking 40000 rows looking for 1100 words.

After running some test I estimated it would take 48 hours to complete in one go -

I have Windows 10 Pro Pc - SSD Hard Drive - 32GB RAM

I tried splitting into 7000 - takes about 9 Hours each

But constantly showing Not Responding - sometimes if I leave it does complete it

But there is no way of knowing at the moment.

I want to ask if there is any ready to use Software or converter application that I can use to complete the task I am doing faster.

Thanks

Comment: Any program that doesn't process a user interface message, like WM_MouseMove, within a certain amount of time become listed as *Not Responding*. Windows has no idea what the program is doing so uses this heuristic. VBA will always be quicker than python because it is in process. I would export it as text and process the text file.

Answer (score 2):

VBA is not slow. Maybe Python is faster, but VBA itself is not that bad. What slows VBA down is the access of Excel data.

You have probably 2 nested loops and inside these two loops, you read one cell of your data and compare it agains a search term (that is also probably read from a cell).

You can dramatically increase the speed of execution if you read all your data in one go into a 2-dimensional array. Then you can do the search in memory.

I made a test sheet (on an old and slow computer), creating 40k rows of random data (in one column) and another 1k of data using as earch terms. The following code took approx 10s.

```
Sub SpeedTest()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    ' Read the data into a 2-dimensioal array (it's in Column 1 = A)
    Dim data As Variant, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    data = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, 1))

    ' Read the search terms into a 2-dimensioal array (it's in Column 10 = J)
    Dim searchTerms As Variant
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).row
    searchTerms = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 10), ws.Cells(lastRow, 10))
    
    ' Loop over all search terms.
    Dim searchIndex
    Debug.Print Now
    For searchIndex = LBound(searchTerms, 1) To UBound(searchTerms, 1)
        Dim x
        x = searchForViaInStr(data, searchTerms(searchIndex, 1))
        
        ' (Here you need to input code that handles the match)
        
        ' You can remove the following lines, I like to add them when execute a large loop
        If searchIndex Mod 50 = 0 Then
            Debug.Print ".";
            DoEvents
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print Now
End Sub

Function searchForViaInStr(data, searchTerm)
    ' Loop manually over the data and use Instr to locate the searchTerm
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    For x = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        For y = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
            If InStr(data(x, 1), searchTerm) Then
                searchForViaInStr = data(x, 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

You will have to tweak it to your needs - the search function currently returns the first string where the search term was found. Maybe you want to return the indices (x and y) so you know where the string was found, maybe you want to continue the search. Also, there might be room for optimization, I just want you to give the idea how to start.